# Indesign - Error 27 "Stack overrun" with app.doScript

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to automate most of my workplace tasks, but I'm somehow stuck.
Part of job consists in placing various photos into an InDesign document for nesting them and creating pdfs to be printed on special custom machines.
Each photo is accompanied by a paper order marked with a order number ranging from 5 to 8 digits and a barcode containing this order number and other information.
The filename of the images contains the order number and I have to place them manually.
Since it's a very time consuming task I thought I'd use a barcode scanner to enter the order barcode (deleting the information I don't need and keeping only the order number) and search inside the photo folder the corresponding image to insert it automatically.
To make it faster I thought of continuously restarting the script in order to insert them one after the other, but after inserting exactly 39 images, this gives me error 27: Stack overrun.
Is there any way to fix this error? In case I have to rewrite the whole script, how do you recommend to do it?
This is the script:

```
    #target "InDesign"
    #targetengine "session"
    if (app.documents.length == 0) {MyImages
        alert ("Open a document first");
        exit ();
        }

//  I've made some research on internet and apparently some user solved the problem increasing the memCache, but it doesn't work in my case

    $.memCache = 9999999999;
    app.scriptPreferences.enableRedraw = false;
    var MyDoc = app.activeDocument;
    MyDoc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.millimeters;
    MyDoc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.millimeters;
    app.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.PAGE_ORIGIN;
    MyDoc.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.PAGE_ORIGIN;
    MyDoc.zeroPoint = [0,0];
    var MyFolder, MyImages, ImgNumber;

//  RestartScript is used to prevent the script from restarting with app.doScript (line 70) if the cancel button is pressed

    var RestartScript = 0;
    var MyPanel = new Window ("dialog", "Enter the barcode");
    var MyText = MyPanel.add ("edittext");
    MyText.preferredSize.width = 150;
    MyText.onChanging = function () {
        MyText.text = MyText.text.replace (/[^0-9]/g, "");

//  This part allows the script to continue automatically once the barcode scanner enters the code which is 15 characters long

        if (MyText.text.length >= 15) {
            BarcodeConversion ();
            MyPanel.close ();
            }
        }

//  The EventListener allows a manual insertion of the image number (if the barcode is not present on the order)

    MyText.addEventListener ("keydown", function (KeyEvent) {
        if (KeyEvent.keyName == "Enter") {
            if (MyText.text != "") {
                ImgNumber = MyText.text;
                MyPanel.close ();
                }
            }
        });

//  The focus is on the edittext for practical purposes

    MyText.active = true;
    var Browse = MyPanel.add ("button", undefined, "Browse");
    Browse.onClick = function () {
        MyFolder = Folder.selectDialog ("Select a folder", " ");
        MyImages = MyFolder.getFiles (/.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|eps|tiff?|psd|pdf|bmp|png)$/i);
        if (MyImages.length <= 0) {
            alert ("There are no images in this folder");
            return;
            }

//  This is for focusing on the edittext automatically after clicking the browse button, but it doesn't work (I don't know why)

        MyText.active = true;
        }
    var Cancel = MyPanel.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");
    Cancel.onClick = function () {
        MyPanel.close ();
        }
    MyPanel.show ();
    if (ImgNumber != undefined) {
        Search ();
        }

//  I'm using app.doScript to restart the same script and automatically insert multiple images in a continuous way (I've tried with MyPanel.show() instead of this to reopen the input panel but it doesn't display well)
//  This is what causes the stack overrun error

    if (RestartScript == 1) {
        app.doScript (new File (app.activeScript.parent.fsName + "\\" + app.activeScript.name) ,ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT);
        }


    function BarcodeConversion () {
        if (MyFolder == undefined) {
            alert ("Folder not selected");
            MyText.text = "";
            return;
            }

//  Here I use slice to remove the part of the barcode I don't need, obtaining the order's number

        ImgNumber = MyText.text.slice (4, 12);
        }


    function Search () {

//  In this function I'm placing all the images with the filename who correspond to the order's number in an array (in case I have multiple images with the same number)

        var ImgFound = [];
        for (var a = 0; a < MyImages.length; a++) {
            if (MyImages[a].name.toLowerCase ().indexOf (ImgNumber.toString ()) != -1) {
                ImgFound.push (MyImages[a]);

//  If there are more images with the same number an alert is triggered and the manual selection is done with openDlg (with the * wildcard character as I work on windows )

                if (ImgFound.length > 1) {

//  A sound alert is triggered, but the volume is too low and doesn't work properly on windows 11 (if someone kwow how to do it in a different way, feel free to share the method)

                    beep ();
                    alert ("There are multiple images with the number " + ImgNumber);
                    var ManualSelection = (File (MyFolder + "/*" + ImgNumber + "*")).openDlg ("Place", undefined, true);
                    if (ManualSelection == null) {
                        Reset ();
                        return;
                        }
                    ImgFound = [];
                    for (var b = 0; b < ManualSelection.length; b++) {
                        ImgFound.push (ManualSelection[b]);
                        }
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }

//  Here i place all the images from the array in the current page and center them

        for (var c = 0; c < ImgFound.length; c++) {
            app.activeWindow.activePage.place (ImgFound[c]);
            MyDoc.align (app.activeWindow.activePage.rectangles[0], AlignOptions.VERTICAL_CENTERS, AlignDistributeBounds.PAGE_BOUNDS);
            MyDoc.align (app.activeWindow.activePage.rectangles[0], AlignOptions.HORIZONTAL_CENTERS, AlignDistributeBounds.PAGE_BOUNDS);
            }
        if (ImgFound == 0) {
            alert ("Image " + ImgNumber + " not present");
            }
        Reset ();
        }


    function Reset () {

//  This function serves to reset the variables to avoid conflicts / errors

        ImgNumber = undefined;
        ImgFound = 0;
        RestartScript = 1;
        }
```

---

**UPDATE**

After some testing, I updated the script with the palette method as Yuri suggested.

```
    #target "InDesign"
    #targetengine "session"
    if (app.documents.length == 0) {
        beep ();
        alert ("Open a document first", " ");
        exit ();
        }
    app.scriptPreferences.enableRedraw = false;
    var MyDoc = app.activeDocument;
    MyDoc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.millimeters;
    MyDoc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.millimeters;
    app.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.PAGE_ORIGIN;
    MyDoc.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.PAGE_ORIGIN;
    MyDoc.zeroPoint = [0,0];
    var MyFolder, MyImages, ImgNumber;
    var MyPanel = new Window ("palette", "Enter the barcode");
    MyPanel.orientation = "column";
    var Group1 = MyPanel.add ("group");
    Group1.orientation = "row";
    var MyPath = Group1.add ("statictext");
    MyPath.preferredSize.width = 150;
    if (MyFolder != undefined) {
        MyPath.text = decodeURI (MyFolder);
        }
    var BrowseButton = Group1.add ("button", undefined, "Browse");
    BrowseButton.onClick = function () {
        MyFolder = Folder.selectDialog ("Select a folder");
        if (MyFolder == null) {
            MyFolder = null;
            MyPath.text = "";
            return;
            }
        MyImages = MyFolder.getFiles (/.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|eps|tiff?|psd|pdf|bmp|png)$/i);
        if (MyImages.length <= 0) {
            beep ();
            alert ("There are no images in the selected folder", " ");
            return;
            }
        MyPath.text = decodeURI (MyFolder);
        }
    var Group2 = MyPanel.add ("group");
    Group2.orientation = "row";
    var MyText = Group2.add ("edittext");
    MyText.preferredSize.width = 150;
    MyText.onChanging = function () {
        MyText.text = MyText.text.replace (/[^0-9]/g, "");
        if (MyText.text.length >= 15) {
            BarcodeConversion ();
            }
        }
    MyText.addEventListener ("keydown", EnterEvent);
    var CancelButton = Group2.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");
    CancelButton.onClick = function () {
        MyPanel.close ();
        }
    MyText.active = true;
    MyPanel.addEventListener ("keydown", EscapeEvent);
    MyPanel.onClose = function () {
        ImgNumber = undefined;
        MyText.removeEventListener ("keydown", EnterEvent);
        MyPanel.removeEventListener ("keydown", EscapeEvent);
        }
    MyPanel.show ();
    function Warning () {
        if (MyFolder == undefined) {
            alert ("No folder selected", " ");
            MyText.text = "";
            return;
            }
        }
    function EnterEvent (EventA) {
        Warning ();
        if (EventA.keyName === "Enter" && MyText.text != "") {
            ImgNumber = MyText.text;
            MyText.text = "";
            Search ();
            }
        }
    function EscapeEvent (EventB) {
        if (EventB.keyName == "Escape") {
            MyPanel.close ();
            }
        }
    function BarcodeConversion () {
        Warning ();
        ImgNumber = MyText.text.slice (4, 12);
        while (ImgNumber.match (new RegExp (/^\d/)) == 0) {
            ImgNumber = ImgNumber.slice (1);
            }
        MyText.text = "";
        if (ImgNumber != undefined) {
            Search ();
            }
        }
    function Search () {
        var ImgFound = [];
        for (var a = 0; a < MyImages.length; a++) {
            if (MyImages[a].name.toLowerCase ().indexOf (ImgNumber.toString ()) != -1) {
                ImgFound.push (MyImages[a]);
                if (ImgFound.length > 1) {
                    beep ();
                    alert ("There are multiple images with the number " + ImgNumber, " ");
                    var ManualSelection = (File (MyFolder + "/*" + ImgNumber + "*")).openDlg ("Inserisci", undefined, true);
                    if (ManualSelection == null) {
                        ImgNumber = undefined;
                        return;
                        }
                    ImgFound = [];
                    for (var b = 0; b < ManualSelection.length; b++) {
                        ImgFound.push (ManualSelection[b]);
                        }
                    ManualSelection = undefined;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        if (ImgFound == 0) {
            beep ();
            alert ("Image " + ImgNumber + " not present", " ");
            }
        for (var c = 0; c < ImgFound.length; c++) {
            app.activeWindow.activePage.place (ImgFound[c]);
            MyDoc.align (app.activeWindow.activePage.rectangles[0], AlignOptions.VERTICAL_CENTERS, AlignDistributeBounds.PAGE_BOUNDS);
            MyDoc.align (app.activeWindow.activePage.rectangles[0], AlignOptions.HORIZONTAL_CENTERS, AlignDistributeBounds.PAGE_BOUNDS);
            }
        ImgFound = [];
        ImgNumber = undefined;
        }
```

Comment: Event listeners persist after the script has finished. Are you removing the event listener at some point? Or do you keep adding it?

Comment: No, I'm not a programmer so I didn't even think about it. Now I've made the event into a function with a removeEventListener at the end of it. The event works fine, but the error 27 is still there, I don't think the event listener was the one causing it.

Comment: It gets me the same error after 74 runs. (Win 7, CS6). I tried to comment out the line `$.memCache` but it doesn't change anything. I have no idea what is wrong out there. Interesting script nevertheless, congrats. Even if it runs only 30 or 70 times before it needs to rerun anew, it does a great job.

Comment: As for "to rewrite the whole script" I'd try to use a palette window instead of a dialog window. Have you tried it? Palettes are intended for continuous operations. Dialogs are for one-run tasks.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it, but I've always had bad experiences with palettes dialog (mainly due to Photoshop), I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to use a palette instead of a dialogue. Here is the short working example how it can be done:

```
#target "InDesign"
#targetengine "session"

var palette = new Window('palette', 'Enter the barcode');

palette.add('statictext', undefined, 'Folder:');
var folder = palette.add('edittext');
folder.text = 'd:\\temp';
folder.characters = 30;

palette.add('statictext', undefined, 'File:');
var file = palette.add('edittext');
file.characters = 30;
file.active = true;

file.onChanging = function() {
    file.text = file.text.replace(/\D/g, '');
}

file.addEventListener('keydown', function(k) {
    if (k.keyName == 'Enter' && file.text != '') {
        place_image(folder.text, file.text);
        file.text = '';
    }
});

palette.addEventListener('keydown', function(k) {
    if (k.keyName === 'Escape') {
        palette.close();  
        // palette = null // for Win CS6
    }
});

palette.show();
// palette.onClose = function() { palette = null } // for Win CS6

//------------------------------------------------------------------
function place_image(folder_name, file_name) {
    var folder = Folder(folder_name);
    var file = File(folder + '/' + file_name + '.jpg');
    if (file.exists) app.activeWindow.activePage.place(file);
}
```

It will show you a palette like this:

[image]

You can input a file name into the second field, press Enter and it will place the jpeg image with this name from the given folder into your document.

As far as I can tell it works fine for this case. No need the doScript clumsy trick. At the very least it got me no errors after I placed about hundred images this way.

You can add any additional functions into it by yourself.

Comment: I did a quick test on a modification of my script, and it seems to work, but I've yet to fix it. I tried yours too but it seems to have some misbehavior at "palette.onClose = function() { palette = null }". Basically when I try to close the palette, InDesign closes itself.

Comment: Yep. It works in Win cs6. On cc it seems the `palette = null` gets the glitch (you can just remove the line). And on macOS it needs another approach (with app.doScript).

Comment: Hi, I updated the script and everything works, however I have some concerns about two things.

Comment: - In line 57 I bound the eventlistener "EscapeEvent" to MyPanel. Yet when I press the Esc button with the focus on MyPanel nothing happens, but when I press it with focus on MyText it triggers EnterEvent first and Escapeevent after (even if EnterEvent should be triggered only with the Enter button).
- Another concern is that even if I add the line "MyText.active = true;" at the end of the BrowseButton.onClick function (line 26), the focus is not put on the edittext MyText after pressing the button and choosing the folder.
Do you happen to know how to solve these little problems?

Comment: Hi! Event listeners are tricky thing. It works different on different OS and versions of InDesign. Right now I tried your updated script in InDesign CS6 Win7 and it works almost ideal. It closes the panel every time I press the Escape key and it keeps focus on the text field always except after press the Browse button. And, alas, I can't tell how it can be fixed. But I'm sure it will work another way on other OS or version InDesign. I'll try it on macOS InDesign CC later.

Comment: Just tried on macOS High Sierra and InDesign 2018. Escape works only when focus on the text field. And palette loses focus every time after I press Enter. So it's pretty useless without a mouse. I suppose it will be the same on the modern macOS and InDesign CC 2023. Event listeners and focusing are fancy beasts. What your OS and version of InDesign?

Comment: I'm working with InDesign CC 2023 on Win11. I guess the best solution is to learn React and redo everything with UXP.

Comment: Yep. UXP looks promising. Extenscript is an ancient technology. It does the job but as for UI it's on the weak side definitely.